# batch insert in neo4j using py2neo 2.0

Tags: neo4j, batch-processing, label, py2neo

I have written this function to insert data as batch but while adding labels I am getting BindError: Local entity is not bound to a remote entity.

```
def bulkInsertNodes(n=1000):
    graph = Graph()
    btch = WriteBatch(graph)
    nodesList = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        temp = Node(id = str(i))
        nodesList.append(temp)
        btch.create(temp)
    btch.run()

    btch = WriteBatch(graph)
    for n in nodesList:
        btch.add_labels(n,"Person")
    btch.run()
```

Comment: Please include the entire exception stack.

Comment: the problem is that im using the nodes in nodesList that are not binded to the remote data. So I have to do that. I have solved it. Thnk you for responding.
    def bulkInsertNodes(n=1000):
        graph = Graph()
        btch = WriteBatch(graph)
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            btch.create(Node(id = str(i)))
        nodesList = btch.submit()
        btch = WriteBatch(graph)
        for n in nodesList:
            btch.add_labels(n,"Person")
        nodesList = btch.submit()